# Javascript: how to change form fields value with single click

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to set the value of three different input text fields with an onclick function.

I have an image that has this code...

```
<img src="images/delete_row.png" width="25" onClick="clearRow(0);" />
```

And I have three input text fields that all have the id of "0".

When I click my image I want to set the value of all three fields to empty.

Can someone please help me write a function that can do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need your `id` values to be different. You should never have the same ID twice on the same page. So lets use this as the example HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="name_0"  name="name" />
<input type="text" id="phone_0" name="phone" />
<input type="text" id="email_0" name="email" />
```

You could use this JavaScript function:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  function clearRow(id){
     var name  = document.getElementById('name_' + id),
         phone = document.getElementById('phone_' + id),
         email = document.getElementById('email_' + id);

     // Clear values
     name.value = phone.value = email.value = "";
  }
</script>
```

And your `img` tag would remain unchanged:

```
<img src="images/delete_row.png" width="25" onClick="clearRow(0);" />
```

Answer (score 1):

> I have three input text fields that
>   all have the id of "0".

This is entirely wrong. In a document you can't have element with the same id. Either use a name or a classname for these textfields and make their ids different.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Change()
    {
        var elems = document.getElementsByName ( "myfields");
        for ( var i = 0;i < elems.length; i++)
        {
            elems[i].value = "";
        }
    }
</script>
<input name="myfields" type="text" id="txt1" />
<input name="myfields" type="text" id="txt2" />
<input name="myfields" type="text" id="txt3" />
<img onclick="Change();" alt="test" src="yourimagpath" />
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#pic').click(function() {
    alert('Clicked on pic - resetting fields')
    $('.field').val('')
  })
}
</script>

<img id="pic" src="image.png">
<input class="field" value="1">
<input class="field" value="2">
<input class="field" value="4">
<input class="field" value="5">
<input class="field" value="6">
<input class="field" value="7">
<input class="field" value="8">
<input class="field" value="9">
<input class="field" value="10">
```

Comment: May be because of the use of jQuery.

Comment: First, I didn't downvote. Second, I imagine the downvote was because you suggested adding a 56K (un-gzipped) JavaScript library in response to how to clear three fields with JavaScript. I *love* jQuery, but sometimes straight JS will get the job done w/o the extra weight.

Comment: @Doug Neiner: jquery would be downloaded *once* (then cached for *an entire year*). you're missing the obvious benefit that using jquery will *save the OP time* when he needs to perform similar functions. (unless you're assuming this is the only javascript he will ever need). jquery is therefore a win, low-level js is less portable, more verbose, more time consuming, etc. your comment assumes a very short-term view (saving a *few insignificant bytes*, but costing the OP by not using a great all-purpose tool for similar reqs.)

Comment: @jspcal How will forcing the OP to learn a completely new framework save him time in this problem? I agree it is not likely this is his *only* JavaScript, but it is equally unlikely that he would go back and rewrite all his other code using jQuery because it was what was suggested for this one answer. Thus, he would end up with all of the overhead with none of the benefit. Like I said, I love jQuery (Check out my #2 placement: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=jquery&sort=stats&pagesize=50), but it is not an end all solution.

Comment: @Doug Neiner: no, not rewrite *old* scripts but use jquery when *similar problems come up again*. jquery is a best practice and a better approach. by your logic, there would *never be a good time* to take 2 minutes to try it. btw, a small design change like adding a field would break the getElementById script, but jquery is fine. why object to broadening someone's toolbox with a cheap and simple tool, especially since this is such a routine use-case for it.

Comment: @jspcal In your answer to the OP, you didn't provide explanation, reasons why jQuery is good, or even why you were including another dependancy. Perhaps he is writing code for a company like one of my clients that allows *no* open source code to be used. I do not object to broadening someone's toolbox but it should be done with explanation and with caveats, if any, listed. Remember, I didn't downvote your answer, I promise!

Comment: @Doug Neiner: you're assuming a pathological case. best practices like jquery *should be the default.* more likely is the client prefers more efficient development and a more powerful system. jquery is *not* something that requires caveats - it's portable, widely-adopted, and the preferred solution. rather than pre-emptively eschewing frameworks (in anticipation of the unlikely requirement that the client *hates industry standards*, or 56k cached would become a burden), it should be recommended as a good approach for this class of problems.

Comment: @jspcal jQuery is not a "best practice" any more than MooTools or Dojo or any other framework for that reason. It currently has the greatest adoption, but that of course could always change. *Now,* regardless of what is and is not the best, you have been around here long enough to know that giving jQuery in answer to a question not tagged "jquery" will get you a downvote unless you provide your reasoning *in* your answer. Not saying it is right, just saying that is how it is.

Comment: @Doug Neiner: jquery and using a framework *are* best practices (as an example, SO uses the same googleapis script i referenced). if the OP doesn't know about jquery, how do you expect him to *tag* it? note, jquery *is* javascript, so even based on the tags it's highly relevant, and ultimately the solution is apropos. by your argument, you couldn't mention any commonly-used library (say zend framework in php or boost in c++) without a lengthy disclaimer in a question tagged by language, which wouldn't be a very good policy.

Comment: @jspcal You *cannot* call jQuery a "best practice" without discounting every existing JS framework. I agree that using *a* framework (for most normal websites) is a best practice, no argument there.

Comment: @Doug Neiner: so you agree. and don't misrepresent what I said. jquery is *one way to achieve best practices* (it happens to be the dominant method). the key is that using *a framework* is obviously better than using none at all. under no circumstances should a correct answer that recommends best practices be downvoted. that said, i'm fine with your answer, i just think that in general, jquery (or insert framework of your choice) is a better option. (note if A is a best practice, and B is an instance of A, B is also a best practice. that should be obvious.)